# SP2013: Unable to find a site collection with query text containing only "WebTemplate:STS". Additional "Path:https://...." parameter is required

Tags: search-results, sharepoint-search

I have a root site collection with URL https://....com, and another site collection with URL https://...com/manpath/00000001, where /manpath/ is a wildcard managed path.

The crawler account has FullRead permission for the whole (the only) web application.

I have a content source set up for all the sites and site collections under the root URL of the web application https://....com:
[image]

Now when I use either search center page or CSOM with query text "WebTemplate:STS" the results don't contain the site collection under the managed path: https://...com/manpath/00000001

But when I explicitly set query text as "WebTemplate:STS AND Path:https://...com/manpath/*" I get the only result: my site collection under the managed path.

Is this an expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of MS support I've found the reason: I can see all the results when **TrimDuplicates=false**. Although I don't really understand how it works with the determination of site collections as duplicates.

I've found a few more articles on the topic with more details about duplicates:

[View Duplicate Results in the SharePoint 2013 Search Center via JavaScript](http://www.eliostruyf.com/view-duplicate-results-sharepoint-2013-search-center-via-javascript/)

[BEWARE OF DUPLICATES IN SHAREPOINT ONLINE’S CONTENT SEARCH WEB PART](http://summit7systems.com/beware-of-duplicates-in-sharepoint-onlines-content-search-web-part/) (with the light description of how duplicates detection works)

[Official MS documentation on TrimDuplicates usage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj687488.aspx)

[Technical description of duplicates detection with hashes](http://blogs.technet.com/b/fesiro/archive/2013/11/11/sharepoint-2013-search-near-duplicates-and-documentsignature.aspx)

[SharePoint 2010 Search: When is a document a duplicate?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14460/sharepoint-2010-search-when-is-a-document-a-duplicate)